# STUSB4500 PD controller: how to find reason for last shut-down?

Tags: power-supply, esp32, usb-pd

I have a PCB using an ESP32 and the STUSB4500 PD controller. For some reason the system would shut-down once in a while but the problem is difficult to reproduce. I'm currently reading the ESP32 reason for last shut-down using:

```
esp_reset_reason_t reason = esp_reset_reason();
```

On the ESP32 the reason seems to be ESP_RST_POWERON and I'm starting to believe that the power-adapter is not working reliably.
Now, my question is: is there a way to read NVM regeisters from the STUSB4500 to understand what's happening? I have tried to check the datasheet but I'm not experienced enough to understand which registers I should be calling and what the values would mean. Anyone out there who can lead me in the right direction?

Many thanks and merry X-mas!

Comment: What leads you to believe that your STUSB4500 has any registers which tell you why it previously shut down? It does appear to have a way to configure a pin to tell you if it's currently shut down due to a fault condition.

Comment: @Cyril Schmidiger Having looked at the datasheet agree with brhans that can't see any registers which record information about why it previously shut down. While the STUSB4500 does have a I2C interface to access NVM registers, the NVM registers just allow user-defined parameters to be customised.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the fault you need to get a USB trace analyzer with Power Delivery and VBUS monitoring capability (like LeCroy [Voyager M310x](https://www.teledynelecroy.com/protocolanalyzer/usb/voyager-m310e) or [Mercury T2P](https://www.teledynelecroy.com/protocolanalyzer/usb/mercury-t2c-t2p)) and check if you have **spikes in current consumption** from your device. Power Delivery is designed to monitor the current/overcurrent to much tighter margins than the old classic USB ports, and the PD chip (on host or your side) might sense something it does not like and disconnect.